# Для чего используется gl_PointSize в WebGL/OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, webgl

В каких случаях используется gl_PointSize в WebGL/OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl_PointSize`, как и `glPointSize` используется для того, чтобы обозначить размер точки (`GL_POINTS`). Различие между ними лишь в том, что `gl_PointSize` используется через шейдер (shader), а `glPointSize` - непосредственно через OpenGL.

Теперь, в каком случае что использовать. Хороший пример для шейдера (и соответственно `gl_PointSize`) - это фонтан частиц.

[image: пример фонтана частиц]

То есть, это такая система частиц, в которой точки могут быть разного размера. Так как мы не можем использовать `glPointSize` для каждой точки индивидуально, этого можно достичь при помощи шейдера.

Пример самого простецкого вершинного шейдера:

```
void main(){
    gl_Position  = ...
    gl_PointSize = pointSize; 
}
```

В данном случае, если переменная `pointSize` постоянна для всех точек, то все точки будут одинакового размера. Зачастую `pointSize` кодируется через один из цветовых каналов (например, альфа канал), и потом изымается в шейдере - в этом случае у каждой точки размер будет определён по-разному.